# plot output size but based only on the graph size but not x-axis label size

Tags: r, plot

Suppose I have two different datasets and I generated exactly the same plot. However the x-tick names (say, "Temperature_California_Jim") of the second plot happen to be longer than the x-tick labels of the first plot (say, "Temperature_California_Wallander"). When I do

```
  pdf("Fig1.pdf",width=5,height=5)
```

and

```
  pdf("Fig2.pdf",width=5,height=5)
```

I often load these plots in an external program like the Inkscape.
Turns out that because in Fig2 the labels of x-tick were longer, the actual
height of the graphs in the output are not identical -- the height of graph region in Fig2 is smaller than the height of the graph region in Fig1.

Is there a way to output figures of defined width and height but basing only on the graph region (i.e. ignoring the extra length required to accommodate the y-tick and x-tick labels?)

Thanks

Comment: Would help immensely to be able to see the code you use, complete with a sample of data from each set.

Comment: or at least upload the figures so that we can see the problem.

Comment: (This assumes base graphics which seems reasonable since yu didn't include code.) Use `par(mai = c(2,2,1,1)` in both cases. Or whatever margins you want.